# Concatenate and uglify with gulp into several files

Tags: javascript, gulp

As a result of this operation I need to obtain two files: vendors.js and bundle.js. They should also be uglified, but variable names must be consistent between them, but so far it either uglification or two files.

```html
<!-- build:js1 vendor.js -->
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
<!-- build:js2 bundle.js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="components/stores.js"></script>
    <script src="components/userInfo/UserInfo.js"></script>   
    <script src="components/userMenu/UserMenu.js"></script>
    <script src="components/components.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the already minified versions provided by AngularJS itself. You should **not** uglify third party dependencies when these are already provided.

Hence you should concat angular and all other angular components into one vendor file and uglify and concat your own javascript.
When you take a look at path bower_components/angular/, there should also be a angular.min.js file (as well as the other angular components).

Take a look at my default setup for GulpJS and AngularJS at https://github.com/elgervb/skeletonSPA. I use a simular approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var concatJS = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('concat-js', function () {
    gulp.src(['one.js', 'two.js'])
        .pipe(concatJS('first.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./javascript'));

    gulp.src(['three.js', 'four.js'])
        .pipe(concatJS('second.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./javascript'));
});
```